# Three expressions Angular if statement

Tags: php, angular

I need to covert the following code from PHP to angular:

```
if ($qty > $dQty+1 || ($qty > $dQty && $dQty > 0))
```

But I don't know how to do this on Angular. This is what I've tried:

```
*ngIf="qty > dQty+1 OR (qty > dQty && dQty > 0)"
```

The problem is the parentheses after **OR**. But I need to compare at this way.

Comment: why OR and not || ?

Comment: You're right.. It worked. I'm not an Angular expert yet. Thank you @David